# Speech biasing using Actions builder webhook fulfillment

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm following the attached article for fulfillment webhook response formats. https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk#provide_speech_biasing

For some reason once I add the speech biasing section, the webhook fails with the error message "Unsuccessful webhook call: Failed to translate JSON to ExecuteHttpResponse.. "

Sample request:
[Webhook format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdWZh.png)

Is there anything specific I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the documentation is wrong.

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDrpb.png)

But the expected format(it is languageCode and a list of strings for speech)

[Expected format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7Rt.png)